# Is there a method to create watershed on google earth?

Tags: watershed, google-earth-pro

I want to create a watershed boundary for a lake only using google earth without using other source of data like srtm etc.

Since we get the height of the location can we use it somehow and create a watershed boundary with effort than digitizing?

Answer (score 2):

Well watershed is quite advanced spatial analysis and I really doubt that Google Earth is focused on this kind of things. I have to say I am not using GE often, but after quick look at capabilities of pro version I would say it is not possible.